# Is avoiding significant advantage by an specific hardware an active goal of the Monero developers?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic-mining

Given that significant advantages in a specific hardware leave out a lot of people that don't posses that specific hardware and leads to mining centralization, is there an active effort to improve the mining algorithm used in Monero to avoid this and harvest the computational power from many devices?

Comment: The question is quite unclear. In particular "improve" can have multiple meanings depending on your perspective. What exactly would you consider an improvement? From our perspective, the CryptoNight algorithm was designed to be ASIC-resistant. In that case "Improve" would mean to make it more resistant. "Hardware-agnostic" implies the opposite, that the algorithm can run well on anything. Pretty sure that's a non-goal.

Comment: What I'm trying to say with "hardware-agnostic" is that no specific hardware obtains a significant advantage over other hardware. Like trying to find a balance. In this sense this would include ASIC-resistance, since it would not make much sense to build ASICs if they don't give you a significant advantage over more general processors.

Comment: @ch4r4c73r can you edit your question based on the comment you just made and differentiate it from the existing ASIC resistance questions? http://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=asic

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

Based on above comments ... No. CryptoNight is the exact opposite of what "hardware-agnostic" means. In particular, CryptoNight is designed to run best on CPUs, and run less efficiently on GPUs and other accelerated compute devices.

An algorithm that is truly hardware-agnostic would run efficiently on any compute device.